# Talk for lay audience: determining private traits and attributes from online behaviour

Tags: statistics

This question was referred from Cross-Validated Stack Exchange:

I need to give a talk on statistic / machine learning as applied to determining an individual's traits and attributes from online behaviour and its use in targeted advertising.

For this I am looking to papers that showcase what is possible today. I am looking on the one hand for papers with a "wow factor" as well as for papers that show the limitations.

Unfortunately this aspect of statistics / machine learning is not really my speciality and I am hoping somebody could give me a few hints / references.

My current starting point is the much publicised facebook-likes study by Kosinskia, Stillwella and Graepelb.

Comment: what's your audience's arena and experience level?